# How do I get Matlab to capture the input names of variables that have arguments inside of them?

Tags: matlab

Take the following function call:

```
Corr1DTimeSeriesMap(NetClimatologySubtracted(:,:,WinterIndices), NAO(WinterIndices));
```

If it were `Corr1DTimeSeriesMap(NetClimatologySubtracted,NAO);` then

```
inputname(1) = 'NetClimatologySubtracted'
```

and

```
inputname(2)= 'NAO'
```

But the `inputname`s disappear once I select for only the `WinterIndices`. The `inputname`s are important for me as I use them for both my plots and filenames that I save the files as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is completely expected behaviour. If you pass

```
NetClimatologySubtracted
```

then you are passing the variable as-is. But, if you are passing

```
NetClimatologySubtracted(:,:,WinterIndices)
```

you are passing an *unnamed* variable, equal to a specific slice of `NetClimatologySubtracted`. It's completely logical that there is no name for an unnamed variable.

You could re-define your function to expect three arguments:

```
Corr1DTimeSeriesMap(NetClimatologySubtracted, NAO, WinterIndices);
```

and then take the slices inside `Corr1DTimeSeriesMap`. But, as already indicated by Bob Gilmore, [this is a bit smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

It is simply better programming practice to de-couple all your functions as much as possible from each other. In your case, that means that `Corr1DTimeSeriesMap` should be able to produce meaningful output *independently* of what variables you happen to throw in.

A *better* approach by far would be to break this dependency on variable names by allowing explicit specification of the label names:

```
Corr1DTimeSeriesMap(...
    NetClimatologySubtracted(:,:,WinterIndices),...
    NAO(WinterIndices), ...
    {'Net climatology subtracted', 'NAO_{45}'});
```

it's more robust, and allows for prettier labels too :)

Labels are (often) already valid filenames, but to make 100% sure, you could use this in conjunction with [genvarname](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) to generate valid filenames from labels specified thusly.

Alternatively, you can also have the filenames as additional argument:

```
Corr1DTimeSeriesMap(...
    NetClimatologySubtracted(:,:,WinterIndices),...
    NAO(WinterIndices), ...
    {'Net climatology subtracted', 'NAO'},...
    {'NetClimSub.txt', 'NAO.txt'});
```

Answer (score 4):

Short answer; you can't.  The INPUTNAME function acts as it does, and many kinds of indexing expressions "break" it (that is, make it return the empty string, '').

Longer answer; while using INPUTNAME makes your life a little more convenient, relying on the variable names and indexing expressions to label your graphs is a **bad** idea.  Because, frankly, it's nobody's business what someone's variables are named in his code, unless he choose to expose them by embedding them in a string.  I've seen plenty of curse words, etc., used as variable names, *especially* in MATLAB code ;-)

Imagine if someone chooses to use your code, and winds up plotting an OMG_I_HATE_MY_BOSS_SO_MUCH variable.  Not cool.

It stinks, and is more work, but please, please, please, make a label a non-optional input argument.