# Possible to get inputnames for variables in a structure?

Tags: matlab

This is how the structure is set up:

```
ClimateSubtractStruct = struct('net',NetClimatologySubtracted,'SW',SWClimatologySubtracted,'LW',LWClimatologySubtracted,'SWCF',SWCFClimatologySubtracted,'LWCF',LWCFClimatologySubtracted,'netclear',netclearClimatologySubtracted,'LWclear',LWclearClimatologySubtracted,'SWclear',SWclearClimatologySubtracted,'Clouds',TotalCloudForcingClimatologySubtracted, 'Precip',PrecipClimatologySubtracted);
fields = fieldnames(ClimateSubtractStruct);
```

Then I call GlobalCorrMap (which uses the inputnames as arguments for the title and filename of the plot). I then intend to use a for loop to run GlobalCorrMap to compare and plot correlations between each of these variables in the structure. An example argument is below:

```
GlobalCorrMap(ClimateSubtractStruct.(fields{1}),ClimateSubtractStruct.(fields{3}))
```

I'm wondering - is it possible for inputname to get the variable name of the variable that's called within structure? Or is it better for me to simply just rename the function so that it can take in the names of the two variables as two separate arguments?

Comment: Or you modify `GlobalCorrMap` to accept the whole struct and two indexes.  This is a design decision and it depends on a number of factors, including what you are comfortable with.

Comment: See your previous questions for answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486542/how-do-i-get-matlab-to-capture-the-input-names-of-variables-that-have-arguments